# AndroidStudio no stacktrace shown after app crash

Tags: android-studio

I simply get no stacktrace information when my app crashes and therefore cannot find any errors. Please help me.[image]

Answer (score 0):

To the left of the stacktrace window, press the bottom button(the one that looks like a redo-button with a stop-icon). It resets the logging. Then you restart the app (and trigger the error) and you should see the error.