# No Stacktrace in AndroidStudio

Tags: android, android-studio, debugging, exception

I´m trying to debug an android app that I´m writing and found out that there is no exception stack trace written to the console / logcat / messages.
I tried to remove the .gradle folder and restarted android-studio, how some post recommend, but it didn´t help me.

I use Android Studio 2.3.1 and tested with a virtual Nexus 5X API 25 and a real Huawei P9 lite with Android 6.0. Problem exists for both devices.

The problem continues to exist also if I remove the google play service dependency.

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:10.2.4'
}
```

My problem seems a bit like this one, but there was no answer for that question:
[AndroidStudio no stacktrace shown after app crash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31036979/androidstudio-no-stacktrace-shown-after-app-crash)

I can find bugs with breakpoints, but this costs me five times more time, then just reading what exception is thrown where.

By the way: the console prints just Log.e messages not Log.d.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read
[what this site is about](http://stackoverflow.com/about) and 
"[How to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask)" 
before asking a question. Your question has virtually no information. The link there is to another question from another user. Please state your problem more clearly if you expect anyone to help you. Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

I have the same happening sometimes. It seems like Android Studio thinks it starts a new debug session and does not show the old logs anymore. 
In that case I change the monitor settings:

1. in the dropdown on the right I choose "No filters"
2. in the dropdown on the left to the search box I choose "Warn" or "Error"

That way I see all error/warn log entries, and sure enough, if there was none after a crash before, it usually appears with these settings.

Do not forget to change back to the preferred settings afterwards.

Comment: tried that before, but I couldn´t see any exceptions

Answer (score 1):

If you are using linux, open a console and type

`adb start-server`

and above logcat tab switch to the new emulator

Answer (score 1):

First, reboot your device and try to trigger the error. IF that does not work, press the bottom button that looks like a redo-button with a stop-icon on it:

[image]

This restarts the Logcat, it does wipe the current log entries showing, but that should show the error when you trigger it.

Comment: The Logcat restarting didn´t work for me. After I rebooted my computer and reopened Android Studio, the exceptions were shown again.

Answer (score 0):

I have seen this issue frequently also.

In my case it was usually caused by the device I was testing on restarting the process/app. This meant that the current view in logcat was for the new process and not the one with the error I wanted.

If you look at the logical window you will see you can actually select the process from the dropdown box - the one you are looking for will probably be there with 'DEAD' after it.

You can see an example here:

[image]

Comment: The exceptions were also not shown in the DEAD process :/